# RewriteRule for Subdirectory

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm new to the Rewrite mod and have been looking over it for the last few days but I am still struggling to get this to work.

I already have a .htaccess file in the root directory that is forcing the secure version of the site and hiding extensions, so that https://www.example.com/help.php goes to https://www.example.com/help

My problem is my admin tool at https://www.example.com/admin

I'd like it to work so that a page like list.php appears as https://www.example.com/admin/list but no matter what I trial, it always either breaks or redirects to the root index file.

Here my root .htaccess file

```
FallbackResource /index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Can anyone help with what I should add to the admin directories .htaccess file, it's a Redhat server if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You might get some useful help if you show your existing `.htaccess` file

Comment: You could also look into using some router library instead. Then you can let one single file take all calls and let the router decide what to do on different URL's. More portable and easier to set up new "virtual" URL's